# How to change Runnable to Thread Use by Textarea

Tags: java, swing

**Chatprogram**

```
private class Receiver extends JTextArea implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String msg = null;
        while (true) {
            try {
            msg = in.readLine(); 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                handleError(e.getMessage());
            } 
            this.append("\n  서버 : " + msg); 
                                                     // 받은 문자열을 JTextArea에 출력
            int pos = this.getText().length();
            this.setCaretPosition(pos); 
                                                  // caret(커서)을 가장 마지막으로 이동
        }
    }
}
```

*i made chat program use by Runnable. but i also want to use Thread. i can't change it. because i study alone. so i want to know how to change it. please help*

Comment: What prevents you from using the `Thread`? eg `new Thread(new Receiver()).start();`

Comment: [all code that creates or interacts with Swing components must run on the event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). What is the use case of a `JTextArea` which implements `Runnable` ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't extend JTextArea. You are not adding functionality to the text area.
2. If your code is blocking waiting for input, then you are correct you should be using a separate Thread so you don't prevent the GUI from responding to events. The easies way to do this is to use a `Swing Worker`. The Swing Worker will execute in a separate Thread and it will allow you to "publish" the data as it becomes available. The published method will execute on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) so you can safely update the text area.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Tasks That Have Interim Results](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) for more information and an example of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

`Runnable` and `Thread` are almost the same, as `Thread` implements Runnable (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), so, if you want to avoid the use of `Runnable`, you just have to extend `Thread` in your class.

Hope this helps.
Regards.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but i want to use thread and textarea at the same time. but if i change runnable to Thread, that time i can't use textarea.

Comment: Sorry, i've read wrong since you are already extending a class. I'm not sure if this could be possible, it would be a design problem as you are asking for multiple inheritance, which doesn't exist in Java and that's the reason of using of Runnable